# Hide form on submit with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

Trying to wrap my head around some Angular items and working thru a tutorial to edit and learn.

Clicking the below button shows the below form. How do I reverse this once the form is submitted? Meaning hiding the form on submit until the button is clicked once more.

```
<button ng-click="addNewClicked=!addNewClicked;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Task
</button>
```

Basically, the form appears, I enter something and submit, but would like the form to dissapear upon submit?  Thinking something to do with ng-hide, but can I do this using only Angular? Or do I need to do something with javascript/css?

```
<div id="addForm" class="margin-full-5">
<form ng-init="addNewClicked=false; " ng-if="addNewClicked" id="newTaskForm" class="add-task">
    <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" ng-model="taskInput" placeholder="Add New Task" ng-focus="addNewClicked">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="addTask(taskInput)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Task
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in your view.

```
<button ng-click="showTheForm = !showTheForm">Add a Task</button>

<form ng-show="showTheForm" ng-submit="processForm()">
    <button>Submit</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="showTheForm = false">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Somewhere in your controller

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
    // execute something
    $scope.showTheForm = false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also achieve this using a combination of Angular form's attribute `$submitted`, `ng-hide` and `ng-submit`

```
<form name="myForm" ng-hide="myForm.$submitted" ng-submit="submit()">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Read about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Answer (score 1):

Your form is displaying *IF* the addNewClicked value evaluates to true, which occurs when you click the add task button. If you want the form to disappear on submit, you just need to make the onClick to that button change your addNewClicked to false.

[AngularJS Docs for Ng-If](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using ng-show/ng-hide as per example below :

```
<form ng-init="addNewClicked=false; " ng-if="addNewClicked" ng-hide="hideform" id="newTaskForm" class="add-task">
```

and modify the submit method to make the hideform = true;

```
$scope.addTask = function(input){
... your things
$scope.hideform = true; 
}
```

You can also do the same using jQuery :

```
$("#newTaskForm").hide();
```

Comment: It is possible to use ng-if but if you only want to show/hide it then preferred to use ng-show/ng-hide instead of ng-if as it remove the form from dom object.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$scope.addTask = function(taskInput) {
    ...
    $scope.addNewClicked = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-show` as you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr1g1kkj/1/)

This will show and hide the div element based on clicking the button. When the button is clicked it will toggle the boolean, hence acting as an on/off switch for `ng-show`